# How to save data from Select box in Entity Framework Database relation Many to Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, dbcontext

How to save data from Select box in Entity Framework Database relation Many to Many

There are two classes one weapon and other User..

public class Weapon { } public class User { }

```
 public class User
        {              
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }      
            }



 public class Wepon
{   public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Wepon_Name { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
```

}

Which should have relation Many to Many Using FormCollection and Model

Comment: Wepon? :) Don't you mean Weapon?

Comment: lol yp spelling mistake :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Class

And Weapon Class

```
public class User
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            **public List<Wepon> WeposInList { get; set; }**

            }



 public class Wepon
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Wepon_Name { get; set; }
        public int Power { get; set; }
        public List<User> UsersHaveWeponsList { get; set; }// User the List for M to M
}
```

- **DBContext**

  ```
   public class DbContexFor : DbContext
      {    
          public DbContexFor()
              : base("name=ConnectionStringName")
          {
          }

          public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
          public virtual DbSet<Wepon> Wepons { get; set; }
      }
      }
  ```

  **
- The Controller Code

**

```
  [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Type")] User user, FormCollection formData)
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var ss = formData["ShipFromCountries"].ToString();
 user.WeposInList = db.Wepons.Where(c => c.Wepon_Name == ss).ToList();
                    db.Users.Add(user);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View(user);
            }
```

And the Html Code

@model enumVarAction.Models.User

@{

```
var list = ViewBag.MyList;
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
```

}

**Create Html Page**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>User</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WeposInList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <select  id="ShipFromCountries" multiple="multiple" name="ShipFromCountries">
                <div class="col-md-10">

                    @foreach (var VARIABLE in list)
                {
                        <option value="@VARIABLE.Wepon_Name">@VARIABLE.Wepon_Name</option>
                    }
                </div>
            </select>
        </div>






        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

[image]

**

- Debug at Controller

**

[image]

**

- Data is Database

**

[image]